# "Realm was compiled with optimisation" under Xcode 7.1.1 using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I've installed realm with Carthage using this tutorial:

[Realm - Swift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

but I have an error while execute this line:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

with error title:

```
Realm was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

Any solutions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't an error. It's just an informational message from lldb.

Comment: Hej, that's correct. I have problem somewhere else (use NSNumber which is forbidden to use in Realm), thats why the crash appeared. Thanks ;)

Comment: what do you mean is not an error? every time im trying to run my app that message apear